# Algorithm: Regex character intersection

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

I have two regular expressions in Java and I would like to know whether the last character of a string (successfully) matched by the first regex can be the same as the first character of a string (successfully) matched by the second one.

These expression are complex, not just character restrictions, but length or form restricted too.

I was looking into https://code.google.com/archive/p/xeger/ but that is just half of the way.

(I am solving a problem whether there is a separator needed in between two consecutive strings restricted by these regexes or whether a parser would be able to tell them apart without a separator)

Examples:

```
Regex1 = <
Regex2 = [:a-zA-Z]([:a-zA-Z]|-|_|\.|[0-9])*
Regex3 = Regex2
```

[Regex1][Regex2] would need no separator, because parser would parse string `<xml` into 2 tokens safely (`<` and `xml`).

[Regex2][Regex3] share a lot of characters and parser would have several possibilities on how to parse lets say string `table`.

I know the theory behind regex evaluation (automata...), however I would like to avoid implementing DFA generation on my own.

Comment: Java? That's important. There is a lot of regex tool not supported by Java, which sucks

Comment: Please show regex you've tried and sample matched string. Also sample of no match string

Comment: Regex1 won't match `<` in `<xml` because of the [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: Sorry, bad expression. I meant to say the parser would match the string into two tokens (given it was trying to match Regex1 and Regex2 somehow). Maybe the anchors don't belong in this example. The problem stays the same though.

Comment: I'm afraid the question you are asking here (last character of first regex = first character of second regex) won't solve your original problem (need of a separator) because the expressions don't necessarily overlap by only one character. Any arbitrary overlap would put you in need of a separator. So I'd suggest an alternative approach: Reverse the second regex and check for common prefixes of the two expressions.

Comment: @mastov yes you're right, good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an open source library on github that can build DFAs for you: http://mtimmerm.github.io/dfalex/

Note that your question seems to be formulated incorrectly.  If you want to know whether or not a delimiter is required between strings that match two regexes, you probably need to know whether any character that can "extend" a successful match of the first regex can also start a match of the second regex.  In a DFA, the characters that can extend a match are the ones on transitions out of accepting states.

I should add that you don't necessarily need to build DFAs to answer these questions.  First + last characters, extending characters, and whether or not it matches the empty string, are questions that can be answered with simple recursive operations on the regex AST.

For example (using | and & for both Boolean and set operations):

Let `NULLABLE(X)` be true iff a regex matches the empty string.  Then:

```
NULLABLE(AB) = NULLABLE(A) & NULLABLE(B)
NULLABLE(A|B) = NULLABLE(A) | NULLABLE(B)
NULLABLE(A+) = NULLABLE(A)
NULLABLE(A?) = true
```

Let `FIRST(X)` be the set of characters that can start a regex:

```
FIRST(AB) = NULLABLE(A) ? FIRST(A)|FIRST(B) : FIRST(A)
FIRST(A|B) = FIRST(A)|FIRST(B)
FIRST(A+) = FIRST(A?) = FIRST(A)
```

Let `EXT(X)` be the set of characters that can extend a regex:

```
EXT(AB) = NULLABLE(B) ? EXT(A)|EXT(B) : EXT(B)
EXT(A|B) = EXT(A) | EXT(B)
EXT(A+) = EXT(A?) = EXT(A)|FIRST(A)
```

Comment: Great, I think I will try to use your library!

Answer (score 0):

Rather an abstract answer, but maybe you are able to turn this into code:

Regular expressions can always be turned into NFAs (Thompson) and therefore into DFAs (Subset Construction). [See this interactive website for examples](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa). And this particular problem might be easier to analyze in a DFA:

*If and only if there is an edge that leads to a final state in the first DFA that is marked with a character, for which there is an outgoing edge of the initial state in the second DFA, then your condition is met.*

See this example for the expressions `aa+b*` and `ba+`. The edges circled in blue are the edges reaching the final state in the first expression, so the final character can be `a` or `b`. The edges circled in red are the outgoing edges in the second DFA, so the first character can be only `b`. In this case, there can be an overlap.

[image: First DFA] [image: Second DFA]

Comment: I understand the theory behind regexes quite extensively, and I have thought about this, but even though there are for sure libraries that build DFAs, I would have to be able to reach inside of these DFAs to retrieve edge information. Generating DFAs on my own would be way to complicated for me as I would have to reimplement full Java regex support.

I was asking this question maybe because I missed a blind spot or somebody might know a good library. Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: @PremekVysoky: Sorry, I was already afraid the answer would be too abstract for your case. I can't come up with any library recommendations, just wanted to explain the theory, in case you can turn it into code easily. Sorry that's not the case.

Comment: Appreciated, I should have mentioned this in the question in the first place (sorry, my first SO question)

Comment: @PremekVysoky: I haven't tried it, but the "Brics" library seems to be able to create DFAs from regexes, and according to the API of the `Automaton` class, you can "reach into it" (get states and transitions): http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html